# How to configure apache and iptables to allow incoming connections ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I am trying to configure my server to allow apache running on port 80 to allow incoming connections. I ran this command

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But Still I can't get the page from other computer browsers but , when I type localhost in my PC browser , everything is fine.Is there any other thing to configure for accepting incoming traffic ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: BTW , should I use the same command if I want port 3306 for mysql to accept?

Comment: Yes, but I recommended , because of security, to do not allow acces to mysql from net.