# Losing hope with Apache2 (IP refused connection)

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I know that this question has been asked before, I've looked at a couple of them too, but for some reason I can't get my server to work.

What I'm trying to do is get access to my website through internet. When I try local (192.168...) it loads and everything is fine.

But when connecting from outside I get IP refused connection.

Few things:

I'm connected directly to the router, nothing in between. 
I do have port forwarding set up. I'm using port 80.
My Ports.conf are set up properly, listening to the port 80
My 000-default.conf is also set up as it should.

What am I missing? On my last machine I got it working in no time, but it seems like I'm missing something here...?

Comment: Do you have `ufw` or another firewall running?

Comment: I have it running, yes

Comment: Quick test - turn it off and see if you can access the website.  If it works, you have found the culprit.  Then open up port 80 and turn ufw back on.

Comment: firewall was disabled, nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

And ofcourse need to save the rules. Iptables-persistent is nice tool for this:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

After it's installed, you can save/reload iptables rules anytime:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save 
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables-persistent reload
```

[How to configure apache and iptables to allow incoming connections ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624036/how-to-configure-apache-and-iptables-to-allow-incoming-connections-ubuntu-server)

Comment: sorry, but it's still not working.

Comment: Connection refused still means that something is blocking the route. Maybe you have missconfigured port forwarding. From the outside you could also trace the packets with Wireshark, maybe will get something more informational

Comment: I know that something is, but I really have no idea what it might be. I just tried running my server on another network, it works like it should. So it's definitely the router on that other network. Thanks for the help though ... :)

Comment: So in conclusion you replaced the router? :)